# Minimizing $P=\frac{\sqrt{5a+8bc}}{8a+5bc}+\frac{\sqrt{5b+8ca}}{8b+5ca}+\frac{\sqrt{5c+8ab}}{8c+5ab}.$

Tags: inequalities

**Olympiad inequality.** Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1.$ Find the minimal value $P$ of $$f:=\frac{\sqrt{5a+8bc}}{8a+5bc}+\frac{\sqrt{5b+8ca}}{8b+5ca}+\frac{\sqrt{5c+8ab}}{8c+5ab}.$$
*Note:* Often Stack Exchange asks to show some work before answering the question. This inequality was used as a proposed problem for the National TST of an Asian country a few years back. However, upon receiving the official solution, the committee decided to drop this problem immediately. They didn't believe that any student can solve this problem in the $3$ hour timeframe.

It seems that minimum is achieved at $(a,b,c)=(0,1,1).$ I've tried to prove
$$f\ge \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{5}. \tag{1}$$
A big problem around here is $a=b=c=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ since $LHS_{(1)}-RHS_{(1)}\approx 0.000151$

I posted it [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802066/minimizing-sum-cyc-frac-sqrt5a8bc8a5bc-with-sum-cycab-1) There is a proof by RiverLi but it's very complicated and not appropriate in contest time.

I hope to see some ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Could you write $f(a,b,c)$ instead of $f$? A function is not the same as one value of a function.

Comment: @YCor Why is my inequality closed?

Comment: I guess you mean, your question, not your inequality. I didn't vote closure, I imagine you can read who voted for closure and the question should be addressed to them, not to me (you didn't address my comment by the way). It is likely that these users believe that MathSE would be more appropriate.

Comment: @YCor "It is likely that these users believe that MathSE would be more appropriate" the problem is this question wasn't answered on MSE even after the bounty and the answer to this question is not available. so I guess this question  fit here

Comment: @pie anyway I didn't make any inquiry and am not the person to ask

Comment: @YCor I don't think that Dragon boy can see who voted for closure. "(List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege)."

Comment: @Dragonboy I did not vote to close. However, MathOverflow is supposed to be for research-level math. I see two ways to interpret your question. (1) Provide any solution at all to the problem. (2) Provide a solution that a contestant could plausibly provide under contest conditions. It seems that (1) has already been answered, and (2) is not a research-type question because mathematical research is not conducted under contest conditions (and anyway, such a solution may not exist).

Comment: @TimothyChow the question is very difficult (It was removed from the contest because it was too hard) and the answer on MSE uses - a Computer Algebra System so doesn't this make the question be difficult enough for MO?

Comment: @pie It's not the difficulty of the problem that is relevant, but whether the question being asked is a research question. To repeat myself, the OP appears to be asking for either (1) any solution at all or (2) a solution findable under contest conditions. (1) is already answered and the trouble with (2) is that mathematical research is not conducted under contest conditions.

Comment: @TimothyChow thank you for explaining that to me